# Looping through Table Records to Update another Tables Records based on a Key Identifier

Tags: sql, database, vba, loops, ms-access

I keep having issues with this query saying there are no reocrds but I know there are because I am looking at the table. I want to loop through a table to find certain column information based off a few parameters on the click of a button.

So when I click my button it'll loop through table one find the fields I need based on the ID and update the other table with those fields.

```
Private Sub GetResults_Click()
  Dim strSQL As String
  Dim SQL As String
  Dim dba As Database
  Dim tbl As Recordset
  Dim rst1 As Recordset
  Dim tstdt As Date

  tstdt = Me.Date.Value

  Set dba = CurrentDb
  Set tbl = dba.OpenRecordset("tbl_Results", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

  strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Results"
  Set tbl = dba.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

  If Not tbl.EOF Then
    With tbl
      .MoveFirst
      Do Until tbl.EOF
        Call getDataRecords(tbl!SystemAssignedPersonID, tstdt)
        .MoveNext
      Loop
    End With
  End If

  Set rst1 = Nothing
  Set tbl = Nothing
  Set dba = Nothing

End Sub

Function getDataRecords(PersonID As Variant, TestDate As Date)
  Dim dba As Database
  Dim rst As Recordset
  Dim rst1 As Recordset
  Dim SQL As String

  Set dba = CurrentDb
  Set rst = dba.OpenRecordset("tbl_Results", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
  Set rst1 = dba.OpenRecordset("dbo_tbl_Random", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
  SQL = "SELECT * FROM dbo_tbl_Random WHERE SystemAssignedPersonID = " & PersonID & " AND Date = " & Date & " AND MenuUsed = 'RandomResult'"

  Set rst1 = dba.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

  rst.AddNew
  rst.Fields("FileSent") = rst1!FileSent
  rst.Fields("Result") = rst1!Result
  rst.Update

End Function
```

Help before I go nuts! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're over-complicating things here. All this can be done in 1 SQL statement

```
Update tbl_Results as Res
Inner join dbo_tbl_Random as rand 
 on Res.PersonID = Rand.SystemAssignedPersonID and Res.[Date] = Rand.[Date] 
set Res.FileSent = Rand.FileSent ,
 Res.Result = Rand.Result
Where Rand.MenuUsed = 'RandomResult'
```

You can execute like this

```
dim sql as string
sql = "Update tbl_Results as Res " & _
"Inner join dbo_tbl_Random as rand  " & _
" on Res.PersonID = Rand.SystemAssignedPersonID and Res.[Date] = Rand.[Date]  " & _
"set Res.FileSent = Rand.FileSent , " & _
" Res.Result = Rand.Result " & _
" Where Rand.MenuUsed = 'RandomResult' "
CurrentDb.Execute(sql)
```

**Update:**

This is how I am expecting your tables are set up

**tbl_results**

[image]

**dbo_tbl_Random**

[image]

How I set up the query in the designer to confirm it is working

[image]

Comment: Do I still have to include my call to open the tables.

Comment: nope. no need to use recordsets at all. You should put that code in the query designer to test the results though. you want to confirm it is truly updating what you want it to update.

Comment: This doesn't work in Access VBA. It keeps giving me and error: expected end of statement on Set??

Comment: I don't need the query to update all of the items for that column each ID number will have different results. It isn't working that way I need a VBA answer not a SQL

Comment: Your VBA is written so that for each `testdate`, `PersonID` combo you find a value in `dbo_tbl_Random` and write that value to the `FileSent` and `result` fields in `tbl_results`, right? That is what this query does. I'll update my answer to show how I am expecting your tables are constructed and you can say if that's right or not.

Comment: Yea its still asking me for a parameter when I try to run the query the parameter is the SystemID and it's not recognizing that.

Comment: Finally!! Thanks for the help. It worked itself out. The SQL statement had the table names backwards, no idea how that happened.